# java IMAP to process email with larger size attachments

Tags: java

Am using java to connect to outlook 2010 to read emails and write it to MQ. If I execute this code in local windows machine , in 2min it reads an email  having a size of 20MB.. But if same code run in UNIX box it takes same time but spike in CPU 60% ..

any suggestion why it is CPU in UNIX ? is it because of environmental restriction like heap size ?

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Currently in JCN , am doing like below piece of code:
Message retrieveEmail= null;
..
//retrieveEmailHelper code connect to Outlook email box using IMAP
..

retrieveEmail= retrieveEmailHelper.getMessageByUid(messageIds[i]);

ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
//writing email in bytestrea

Comment: sorry.. i have corrected my problem statement..